# Retain count in objective C return -1

Tags: objective-c, retaincount

I'm new to objective C, I have a NSMutableArray with 3 objects in it, then I try to print the retainCount of the array. Why the final retainCount return -1? Thanks

```
NSLog(@"myArray has retain count of %d", [myArray retainCount]);    
[myArray release];
NSLog(@"myArray has retain count of %d", [myArray retainCount]);
```

Result from console:

```
2010-10-17 11:58:06.407 TestRetainCount [527:a0f] myArray has retain count of 1
2010-10-17 11:58:06.407 TestRetainCount [527:a0f] myArray has retain count of -1
```

Answer (score 3):

After an object has been deallocated (which may happen after a release), you can no longer rely on its data being intact. You're trying to trust the retain count after it has become invalid.

On a general note, don't use the retain count. Ever. Use the rules in the memory management programming guide, and you'll always get the reference counting correct.

Answer (score 1):

Graham Lee answered the question specific to your example.

not specific to your example, but to your question (subject):

`UINT_MAX` is often used to denote an object which uses no reference counting (e.g., is never deallocated, such as a singleton), or a custom reference counting implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Can't rely on an accurate retainCount because of the timing autoreleased objects. That said, count your alloc/init, new, retains, etc... and match with corresponding release.

Comment: There is no retain count in GC (at least not in ObjC terms). And, as Graham said, you can effectively never see a retain count of 0 because the object is already deallocated by that time.